# nrwl/nx-set-shas not getting previous successful commit

Tags: git, continuous-integration, circleci, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm currently encountering an issue while using nx-set-shas in my project. According to my understanding, nx_base should capture the last successful commit of the remote feature branch in CircleCI, and nx_head should represent the current commit. To achieve this, I have set the main-branch-name to $CIRCLE_BRANCH in the configuration.

However, I have noticed that both nx_base and nx_head have the same value, which corresponds to the commit I just pushed. This seems contradictory to my expectation of nx_base representing the last successful commit of the remote feature branch.

I have followed the setup instructions for nx-set-shas, but it seems that there might be something misconfigured. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  nx: nrwl/nx@1.6.1

jobs:
  lint:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm ci
      - nx/set-shas:
          main-branch-name: $CIRCLE_BRANCH
      - run: npx nx format:write
      - run: npx nx affected --base=$NX_BASE -t lint --parallel=3

  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm ci
      - nx/set-shas:
          main-branch-name: $CIRCLE_BRANCH
      - run: npx nx affected:test --base=$NX_BASE --parallel=3
```

Here's the same value from CircleCI:
[Circle CI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9k3S.png)

I have reviewed the source code of nx-set-shas and it appears to fetch the last successful commit from CircleCI. But in my case, how is it possible to capture the commit I just pushed? Shouldn't nx_base correspond to the last successful commit of the remote feature branch?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, explanations, or suggestions on how to correctly configure nx-set-shas to capture the previous successful commit of the remote feature branch. Thank you in advance!